# Wget - download all links from a http location (not recursivly)

Tags: wget

I have a link to an http page that has a structure like this:

Parent Directory                                          -
[DIR] _OLD/                                01-Feb-2012 06:05    -
[DIR] _Jan/                                01-Feb-2012 06:05    -
[DIR] _Dec/                                01-Jan-2012 06:05    -
......
[DIR] _Apr/                                01-May-2011 06:05    -
[DIR] _Mar/                                01-Apr-2011 06:05    -
[DIR] _Feb/                                01-Mar-2011 06:05    -
[DIR] WEB-INF/                             21-Aug-2009 13:44    -
[   ] nohup_XXX_XXX21.out       14-Feb-2012 09:05  1.6M
[   ] XXX_XXX21.log             14-Feb-2012 09:04   64K
[   ] XXX_XXX21_access.log      14-Feb-2012 08:31  8.0K
[   ] XXX_XXX21_access.log00013 14-Feb-2012 00:01  585K

I would like to downlload only the files present in the root directory...the xxxx files.

I have a solution using

```
curl -U Mozilla http://yourpage.com/bla.html > page
grep -o http://[^[:space:]]*.*log* page > links
wget -i link
```

but i wonder is not possible to do that only using wget ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

All files from root directory matching pattern *.log*:

```
wget --user-agent=Mozilla --no-directories --accept='*.log*' -r -l 1 http://yourpage.com/bla.html
```

- --user-agent=Mozilla set User-Agent header
- --no-directories save all files in current directory
- --accept='*.log' accepted extensions (pattern)
- -r recursive
- -l 1 one level of recursion

You avoid grepping out html links (could be error prone) at a cost of few more requests to server.

Comment: tried but does not work yet

Comment: @Cris Could you post command output somewhere? It works for me on similar URL.

Comment: @Cris I added --user-agent wget option to mimic your curl command more.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/0U5pWYfz   Thanks

Comment: @cris Can you confirm that there are links <a href="http://..."> to XXX_XXX21.log files in first index.html?

Comment: here is the html i 'attack': http://pastebin.com/TQceUufs

Comment: now it works !!! i should have put *.log* instead of '*.log*'